# Is there a way to express a Postgres literal int in hexadecimal?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a big list of hexadecimal numbers I'd like to insert into a PostgresQL table. I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO foo (i)
VALUES (0x1234);
```

...but that didn't work. Is this possible?

Answer (score 26):

As you've noted, you can start with a [bit-string constant](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) written in hexadecimal, and then [type-cast it](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) to the type you want. So,

```
INSERT INTO foo (i) VALUES (CAST(x'1234' AS int))
```

or

```
INSERT INTO foo (i) VALUES (x'1234'::int) -- postgres-specific syntax
```

Answer (score 10):

This seems to work:

```
 CAST(X'3e000000' AS INT)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just use

```
x'1234'::int;
```

For more information see my post on,

- [How do I write a hex literal in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/203358/2639)